# CiviRules Menu Not Displaying

Tags: civirules

After installing CiviRules on CiviCRM 5.11, the Rules menu does not display.  We are running Drupal 7.67.  Have flushed cache, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you also using a newer CiviRules. It used to have its own top level menu, but its now under Administer.

Comment: Thanks-- that was it.